Selecting cells adjacent to empty cells
So here is an example,
I want select the cells adjacent to empty cells (e.g Numbers which are in bold) and move them up to the third column on the side of the same number.
I have data in following format:
A   1    
B   2    
    2    
C   3    
D   4    
    4    
E   5    
F   6    
    6    
G   7    
    7    
H   8    

I want the output in following format:
A   1    
B   2   2
         
C   3    
D   4   4
         
E   5    
F   6   6
         
G   7   7
         
H   8    

Can anyone help since the data I have is much bigger near to 500 rows.
Thank you!
I think once I select the cells adjacent to the empty cells I can just copy and paste the cells in the third column a row above. that will solve the problem, but the only thing is that there are hundreds of cells, and I don't want to select each cell manually.

to do this in place will require vba.  Formula will not "move" a value.  They can replicate but the original will stay and will need to stay for the formula to continue to work.

Is there any chance of a third instance or that the duplicates would not be immediately below the matching value?

As mentioned by @ScottCraner Sir, you need VBA, but if you want you can use Power Query and import back to Excel, and just remove the connection from the source and delete the source as well, to work on the newly imported data.

Another way by creating another range with desired result, copy and paste the values.
To get the result:

Fill the empty values in col1 with non-empty values from above, by for each row (with index i), if the cell is empty, find the non-empty cell by searching in reverse XLOOKUP(TRUE … -1) in all the cells above TAKE(col_1, i)

MAP(
SEQUENCE(ROWS(col_1)),
LAMBDA(i, IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(col_1, i)), XLOOKUP(TRUE, NOT(ISBLANK(TAKE(col_1, i))), TAKE(col_1, i), , , -1), INDEX(col_1, i)))),


Filter col2 using this list and form rows for matching values

HSTACK(INDEX(col_1, cur), 
TOROW(FILTER(col_2, col_1_empty_filled = INDEX(col_1_empty_filled, cur)))))))), 1)


Vertically stack these rows.

Assuming you have Microsoft 365.
Enter the following in cell with enough rows below, adjusting for the values col_1 and col_2 to match your data (D1 in the example):
=LET(col_1, A1:A12, col_2, B1:B12,
col_1_empty_filled, MAP(
SEQUENCE(ROWS(col_1)),
LAMBDA(i, IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(col_1, i)), XLOOKUP(TRUE, NOT(ISBLANK(TAKE(col_1, i))), TAKE(col_1, i), , , -1), INDEX(col_1, i)))),
empty_added, DROP(REDUCE("", SEQUENCE(ROWS(col_1_empty_filled)), LAMBDA(acc,cur,
VSTACK(acc, IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(col_1, cur)), "",
HSTACK(INDEX(col_1, cur), TOROW(FILTER(col_2, col_1_empty_filled = INDEX(col_1_empty_filled, cur)))))))), 1),
IFNA(empty_added, ""))




Formatted:
=LET(
    col_1, A1:A12,
    col_2, B1:B12,
    col_1_empty_filled, MAP(
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(col_1)),
        LAMBDA(i,
            IF(
                ISBLANK(INDEX(col_1, i)),
                XLOOKUP(TRUE, NOT(ISBLANK(TAKE(col_1, i))), TAKE(col_1, i), , , -1),
                INDEX(col_1, i)
            )
        )
    ),
    empty_added, DROP(
        REDUCE(
            "",
            SEQUENCE(ROWS(col_1_empty_filled)),
            LAMBDA(acc, cur,
                VSTACK(
                    acc,
                    IF(
                        ISBLANK(INDEX(col_1, cur)),
                        "",
                        HSTACK(
                            INDEX(col_1, cur),
                            TOROW(
                                FILTER(col_2, col_1_empty_filled = INDEX(col_1_empty_filled, cur))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        1
    ),
    IFNA(empty_added, "")
)


This is easily achieved by combining a formula with the Filtering feature:

Enter the formula
=IF(AND(A3="",A4<>""),A3,"")

in the 2nd cell of the 3rd column and copy it down for the length of your data.
Once the formulae have been written to the 3rd column, copy them and Paste Special -> As Values to hard-code the values.
All 3 columns should then be filtered, with the criterion of Blanks applied to the 1st column:

All of the visible cells in the 2nd column (below the "Filter header" row) should then be selected

and the DELETE key pressed to clear them.
Subsequently removing the filter will result in the following layout:


Transform Data: Move Cell Adjacent to Blank Cell
Simple (D2:E13,F2:F12)

You could use the following simple formulas in D2, E2, and F2:

=IF(A2="","",A2)
=IF(A2="","",B2)
=IF(A3="",B3,"")


Copy the 3rd one down only to the cell (F12) before the last so you don't get the 0 picked up from below the last cell.
If you don't want to keep this copy, you don't need column D.
Just copy E:F and paste as values to B.


M365 (H2:J13)

You could use the following spilling formula in H2:
=LET(t,A2:A13,n,B2:B13,
    HSTACK(IF(t="","",t),IF(t="","",n),
        VSTACK(DROP(IF(t="",n,""),1),"")))

which is a short version of the following educational formula:
=LET(td,A2:A13,nd,B2:B13,
    t,IF(td="","",td),
    n,IF(t="","",nd),
    ne,IF(t="",nd,""),
    ns,VSTACK(DROP(ne,1),""),
    r,HSTACK(t,n,ns),
    r)


Similarly, you could make it a bit more dynamic using:
=LET(data,A2:B13,text_col,1,num_col,2,
    t,CHOOSECOLS(data,text_col),
    n,CHOOSECOLS(data,num_col),
    HSTACK(IF(t="","",t),IF(t="","",n),
        VSTACK(DROP(IF(t="",n,""),1),"")))

which is a short version of the following educational formula:
=LET(data,A2:B13,text_col,1,num_col,2,
    td,CHOOSECOLS(data,text_col),
    t,IF(td="","",td),
    nd,CHOOSECOLS(data,num_col),
    n,IF(t="","",nd),
    ne,IF(t="",nd,""),
    ns,VSTACK(DROP(ne,1),""),
    r,HSTACK(t,n,ns),
    r)


Study the educational formulas by replacing the last r with any other variable.

Alternatively, you can see the results of the other variables in L2:Q13.


